# Last item on the list in RecycleView has wrong position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making Activity in which I want to display list with RecycleView.
The problem is when I try to remove item from the list. If there is only one item left it has wrong index 1 instead of 0.

If i remove item from last to first everything works great. However if I remove items starting from the first item to the last an bug occurs.
So I have a list

```
Item1 - has index 0
Item2 - has index 1
Item3 - has index 2
```

after deleting Item1:

```
Item2 - has index 0
Item3 - has index 1
```

after deleting Item2:

```
Item2 - has index 1
```

as you see item2 should disappear, but it is there and has wrong index.

If I am using `notifyDataSetChanged();` the items are removed properly, but the names from the list disappear from last to first no matter in which order I remove items.

```java
class MyLocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<Localization> localizations;
    private MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

    public MyLocationAdapter(List<Localization> localizations) {
        this.localizations = localizations;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.location_item, parent, false));
        return myViewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String locationName = localizations.get(position).name;
        myViewHolder.name.setText(locationName);
        myViewHolder.addFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp);
        myViewHolder.deleteLocation.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);


        myViewHolder.deleteLocation.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Log.d("Removed ", "" + localizations.get(position).name);
            localizations.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount(), null);
        });
    }
```

Error I got if I try to remove last item that has wrong index and name of second to last item. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.maciej.astroapp.Location.MyLocationAdapter$override.lambda$onBindViewHolder$1(MyLocationAdapter.java:48)
        at com.example.maciej.astroapp.Location.-$$Lambda$MyLocationAdapter$override$Yyi4W6TnKa-g0MRulbiyIxpVNZ0.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `position` inside `setOnClickListener` put `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: It repairs index, now the last item has index 0. I have changed ```notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount(), null);```  to ```notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), getItemCount(), null);``` and the name is also correct.

Comment: But why argument ```position``` does not  work. I cannot understand why it is there if I cannot use it.

Comment: @mcfb because the `position` variable is captured inside a lambda (the click listener). This lambda will be called *later* with a previous and wrong value of `position`.

Comment: @Mousa and @MONK I have last question why ```notifyDataSetChanged();``` does not work. It is not best for performance but it should work also.

Comment: You saved me!! I was trying to solve my bug for couple of days now, thank you for your answer.